# Accessing MVC controller method from typescript

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed web application with ASP.Net MVC + ANGULAR 4 (Typescript) in visual studio. Now I need to call some methods of HomeController from angular code.
Is there any way for doing that?

Comment: You have to expose that code via an action method and your angular code can call it via ajax

Answer (score 0):

The angular app can call the method using HTTP. It seems you basically want to use the ASP.Net MVC as an API, which might be better done using WebAPI. Have the server side method return a JSONResult object. If you are using Angular 4, you probably don't want the server returning its own views.